# HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request on translate TextBlob

Tags: python, translation, translate, textblob, google-translation-api

I'm trying to translate a text with the TextBlob library, but the following HTTPError error is appearing: `HTTP Error 400: Bad request`, can someone help me with this?

Observation:
I'm using VSCode to run this script, and I can't use googletrans due to certification in my work.

```
from textblob import TextBlob
b = TextBlob("The weather is beautiful today. Tomorrow looks like bad weather.")

b.translate(to='es')
```

Comment: There is a similar reported issue in https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/issues/401 it is better to add on to the github issue.